# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pyramid==1.3a7

Tags: python, pyramid, pkg-resources

So, a few days ago, I was trying to boot up Django with pyramid and work some web magic way outside of my skillset and ended up messing up a lot of important things. For a while I couldn't even run python. I ended up fixing that by changing my system variable PYTHONHOME.

Now I am running into problems with pserve. When I run pserve development.ini --reload I am getting a traceback:

```
File "C:\env\Scripts\pserve-script.py", line 5, in <module>
   from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2607, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pyramid==1.3a7
```

any suggestions on what to look for? I have two friends that are able to run everything, so if there is anything I should be comparing to, I can do that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up deleting the environmental variables PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH and everything is working as before.

I assume it was looking in some incorrect directories because of those system variables and thus not being able to locate my version of pyramid.